# Cannot Install a Managed Service Account via DevOps

Tags: sql, powershell, azure-devops

I have a problem i have tried to debug all day now and unable to find a solution.

**The Problem**

I am trying to automate SQL server builds within a pipeline.  I am trying to create and install MSA's.  I can add the computer service accounts into AD with the first two commands but when i try to install it on the SQL server, this fails.

My Script so far:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$MSA,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$server,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$agentaccount,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string]$agentpass
)

# Create Creds
[string]$userName = $agentaccount
[string]$userPassword = $agentpass
[SecureString]$secureString = $userPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
[PSCredential]$credentialObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $secureString

#Create SVS account and add it to the computer object
$SVS = $MSA + "SVS"
try {
    New-ADServiceAccount -name $SVS -Enabled $true -RestrictToSingleComputer -Credential $credentialObject
    Add-ADComputerServiceAccount -Identity $server -ServiceAccount $SVS -Credential $credentialObject
    Write-Host "$SVS Created"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "$SVS already exists"
}

...


#Add the new MSA accounts to the "SQL Server account permissions" group
Add-ADGroupMember "SQL Servers" ($SVS + '$') -Credential $credentialObject

#Create powershell script to install all service accounts onto the required server
#Script Block to run
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -Force 
Install-ADServiceAccount -Identity $SVS 

...
```

When i run `Install-AdServiceAccount -Identity $SVS` the Error output is:

```
install-adserviceaccount [serviceaccount]

install-adserviceaccount : Cannot install service account. Error Message: 'An unspecified error has occurred'.
At line:1 char:1
 + install-adserviceaccount [serviceaccount]
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: ([serviceaccount]:String) [Install-ADServiceAccount], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InstallADServiceAccount:PerformOperation:InstallServiceAcccountFailure,Microsoft.ActiveD
   irectory.Management.Commands.InstallADServiceAccount
```

**Tried so far**

- Ran a powershell task within a Deployment group with the SQL server being a member
- Ran a remote target powershell task via an agent to try an invoke the script as an admin.
- Created the script locally on the SQL server and invoked the script via a remote target powershell task above too.

** Issue **

When i run this manually on the server when in an Administrator Powershell, the `install-adserviceaccount` works fine.  I guess my question is, is there anyway i can get powershell running as an administrator user from within the pipeline?

Or does anyone have any idea how to solve this.

Thanks.